Why I get a termlabels error in nomogram, using the creator example?
library(rms)
n <- 1000    # define sample size
set.seed(17) # so can reproduce the results
d <- data.frame(age = rnorm(n, 50, 10),
                blood.pressure = rnorm(n, 120, 15),
                cholesterol = rnorm(n, 200, 25),
                sex = factor(sample(c('female','male'), n,TRUE)))

# Specify population model for log odds that Y=1
# Simulate binary y to have Prob(y=1) = 1/[1+exp(-L)]
d <- upData(d,
  L = .4*(sex=='male') + .045*(age-50) +
       (log(cholesterol - 10)-5.2)*(-2*(sex=='female') + 2*(sex=='male')),
  y = ifelse(runif(n) < plogis(L), 1, 0))

ddist <- datadist(d); options(datadist='ddist')


f <- lrm(y ~ lsp(age,50) + sex * rcs(cholesterol, 4) + blood.pressure,
         data=d)

nom <- nomogram(f, fun=function(x)1/(1+exp(-x)),  # or fun=plogis
    fun.at=c(.001,.01,.05,seq(.1,.9,by=.1),.95,.99,.999),
    funlabel="Risk of Death")

Error in reformulate(attr(termobj, "term.labels")\[-dropx\], response = if (keep.response) termobj\[\[2L\]\],  : 'termlabels' must be a character vector of length at least one
This is the example code that is in the nomogram package (version 6.8-1). Does anyone know how to correct the error?
I have tried with other examples from google and the package and I always get the same error

Are you using any user-contributed R packages? If so, please add them to your R code.

Yes, I'm using the library rms.

Your code works for me in the sense that there are no errors (or warnings). Suggest you start a fresh R session and try again (copy and paste only the code you provided).

Which version of the package are you using? And the version of R?

rms version 6.8-1. R 4.4.1.

Ty for the help Edward

Does it work now? Which command is causing the error?

It already works, the problem was that it requires R version 4.4.1.
